# Evaluating $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{4 n-3}+\frac{1}{4 n-1}-\frac{1}{2 n}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{4 n-3}+\frac{1}{4 n-1}-\frac{1}{2 n}\right) = \;?$$

---

I have been trying to see if it can be written as sum of two telescope terms but it looks tricky. Any help ?

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: Oh okay thank you for editing :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: The sum is a rearrangement of the terms of the alternating harmonic series.

Can you find a series to compare term-wise to? Note that $-\frac{1}{2n} = - \frac{1}{4n} - \frac{1}{4n}$.

---

Since everyone is very hectic in the comments, let me be clear here:

The sum converges. The rearrangement itself is **not** enough to prove this, of course, since the harmonic series converges conditionally. However, my hint that it is a rearrangement was to hint at the possibility that we can use a comparison to prove it.

---

**Full solution**

$
\sum \left( \frac{1}{4n-3} + \frac{1}{4n-1} - \frac{1}{4n} - \frac{1}{4n} \right) = \sum \left(\frac{1}{4n-3} - \frac{1}{4n-2} + \frac{1}{4n-1} - \frac{1}{4n}\right) + \sum \left( \frac{1}{4n-2} - \frac{1}{4n}\right).$

$= \ln 2 + \frac{1}{2} \sum \left( \frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n} \right) = \frac{3}{2} \ln 2.$

Comment: but it's somewhat of an infinite/nasty rearrangement, since the odd-denominator terms are much higher than the even-denominator terms in any given partial sum.

Comment: Yep - this was a very "just for starters" kind of hint.

Comment: ah got it. I guess our comments give a second hint then.

Comment: Yes I have noticed that and since it is n rearrangement of a conditionally convergent series, it need not converge to $\ln 2$ right

Comment: note $-\frac1{2n} = -\frac1{4n}-\frac1{4n}$

Comment: @lilly In fact using the hint you can write out the difference between
$$\sum_{n=1}^k \frac1{4n-3} + \frac1{4n-1} - \frac1{2n} - \sum_{n=1}^l \frac{(-1)^k}k$$
An see that it grows like the harmonic series.

Comment: @lilly: That is absolutely right. The rearrangement is not allowed in this case.

Comment: @TonyK My mentioning of the rearrangement is that it makes a next possible step of *comparison* perhaps more natural.

Comment: Let's be clear here -- I think @Soke is on team "it diverges" and views this hint as a first step to prove that. But the hint could be misread as "it converges because it can be rearranged." (I am on team "it diverges.")

Comment: @hunter No, I am on team "it converges," and I am mentioning the rearrangement to give OP some insight on a possible comparison to prove this.

Comment: @Soke got it, finally!

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

You might compare the partial sum for $n=1$ to $k$ with $\frac11 -\frac12+\frac13 -\frac14+\cdots -\frac1{4k}$, which has a well known limit.

Added:

If you do, you will find the difference is $\left(\frac12-\frac14\right)+\left(\frac16-\frac18\right)+\cdots+\left(\frac1{4‌​k+2}-\frac1{4k}\right)$ which is half $\frac11 -\frac12+\frac13 -\frac14+\cdots -\frac1{2k}$.

So the limit of the original sum is $$\log_e 2 + \frac12 \log_e 2 \\=\frac32 \,\log_e 2.$$

Comment: You can't rearrange terms like this if the series is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: @TonyK _compare with_. Comparison will give a result.

Comment: @TonyK:  You can rearrange a finite number of terms in a partial sum.

Comment: @Henry I'm not convinced the partial sum goes out the way you said. For example, exanding out to $n = 2$ gives
$(1 + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{2}) + (\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{4})$

Comment: @hunter hence *compare with*. Note that $- \frac{1}{2} = -\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: how do you prove a series is divergent by comparing to a convergent series ?

Comment: @hunter The series is convergent.

Comment: @hunter: the difference between the partial sums is $\left(\frac12-\frac14\right)+\left(\frac16-\frac18\right)+\cdots+\left(\frac1{4k+2}-\frac1{4k}\right)$,   which is half of something familiar

Comment: @Henry got it, thanks !

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^k \left(\frac{1}{4 n-3}+\frac{1}{4 n-1}-\frac{1}{2 n}\right) =1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\cdots-\frac{1}{2k} + \sum\limits_{n=k}^{2k-1} \frac{1}{2n+1}$$

Can you evaluate the limits of the two series on the right-hand side?